# ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/index.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

**This is complete error report**

ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/index.js 1:0-88
export 'keyframes' (reexported as 'keyframes') was not found in '@mui/styled-engine' (possible exports: GlobalStyles, StyledEngineProvider, default)

Comment: Please, add more context.

Comment: I can share the code of my cards component and what ever you acquired, just comment here for code

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/system/esm/index.js 1:0-88
export 'css' (reexported as 'css') was not found in '@mui/styled-engine' (possible exports: GlobalStyles, StyledEngineProvider, 
default)
 @ ./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/index.js 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 
2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 2:0-191 14:0-51 14:0-51
 @ ./src/CardGrid.js 15:0-46 20:13-19
 @ ./src/Main.js 7:0-38 98:39-47
 @ ./src/App.js 12:0-30 92:35-39
 @ ./src/index.js 6:0-24 10:33-36

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the bellow

1. **For npm**

npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled

2. **For Yarn**

yarn add @emotion/react @emotion/styled